# How can I style arbitrary text in the Front End?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, separation-of-concerns, presentation

say I'm displaying a List of messages from the server on a page by iterating the List. Also say that certain portions of some message text need to be emboldened e.g.

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is a nice message</li>
  <li>This is a warning message about <b>some business rule</b> being broken</li>
</ul>
```

Now obviously we don't want display logic in the server code which builds the messages. But we also don't want business logic in the front end e.g. where it would grep for a list of known business rules and wrap them in bold tags.

Perhaps a half-decent approach would have the server inserting our own tags into the text for parsing in the front end e.g.

```
   This is a nice message
   This is a warning message about %%%some business rule%%% being broken
```

where the front end code simply emboldens the %%%-bounded text. But that feels far from optimal. How could we best do it? BTW technologies involved are an ASP.NET backend and a thin but JS-enabled front end. Thanks!

Comment: Your backend should be responible for *marking* business rules. This could be by wrapping them in a `span` or `div` element, with a class of `business_rule`. Your presentation layer is then responsible for rendering this (e.g. by using CSS to bold anything matching `.business_rule`).

Comment: Note that HTML5 brings new mechanisms for custom elements - see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/ for example.

Comment: thanks @RB that's not a bad shout. We're emitting an HTML email so HTML5 is waaaay out the window. However by putting `div`'s in the code, we are still binding the backend to (one tag of) HTML which isn't ideal. But I don't fancy dealing with XML TBH!